# Read txt with different lines format and create objects?

Tags: java, file, oop, java.util.scanner, filereader

I have a txt file with name and last name/s and I need to create users from it.
For example, I have in the txt values like this:

```
Beckham, David
Lopez Vega, Maria
Graham Daniels, Luke
```

The problem is that users are created just with the first last name and the name (ignoring second last name in case it have it).
I don't know how to take that information and create an object with it.
The object class is simple:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public Student(String name, String lastName) {
        this.name= name;
        this.lastName= lastName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getlastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setlastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```

I've tried this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Students.txt"));

List<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();
while(input.hasNext()) {
    String name= input.next();
    String lastName = input.next();

    Student student= new Student(name, lastName);
    students.add(student)
}
```

But it doesn't works. I've being trying for a while but I can't get from the file just the info I need.

Comment: It will be beneficial for you to learn `split()` method of `String` class..

Comment: Add following code at the end of your Students.java DTO class to have better output. `@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }`

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm reading about it right now, thanks :)

Comment: @nanomader i added it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd read an entire line and parse it by calling `split`s:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Students.txt"));

List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] splitLine = line.split(", ");

    String name = splitLine[1];
    
    String[] splitLastName = splitLine[0].split(" ");
    String lastName = splitLastName[0];

    Student student = new Student(name, lastName);
    students.add(student);
}
```

Comment: Change "input.split(", ");" to "line.split" to make it work. And add semicolon on the last line of your code.

Comment: @nanomader good catch WRT `line` vs `input`. The missing semicolon was copy-and-bugged from the OP, but also a good catch, thanks! Edited and fixed.